# Highcharts - Show tooltip on points click instead mouseover

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have tool tip on clicking of points instead of mouse move.

I have tried with showing values in java script alert as below

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Requirement is to show high chart tool tip on click.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you accept any of answers in your questions? Even when you said it worked, you still didn't click  accept-sign on the left side of the answer. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). And about your question - it's not supported by official Highcharts API. However, I would try to use `chart.tooltip.refresh(point)`.

Comment: Check [HERE](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @PawelFus states, it's not officially supported but you can fudge this in by taking control of the visiblity of the tooltip.

<s>First on chart load, hide it:</s>

```
       chart: {
            events: {
                load: function(){
                    $('.highcharts-tooltip').hide();
                }
            }
        },
```

Disable sticky tracking, and on mouseout hide it, on click show it:

```
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stickyTracking: false,
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        $('.highcharts-tooltip').show();
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        $('.highcharts-tooltip').hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/).

First attempt only worked in chrome, here's another:

Disable the default tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},
```

In the chart load event, create your own:

```
 chart: {
     events: {
        load: function(){
            this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);                    
         }
     }
 },
```

In the click and mouseout control it:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        events: {
            click: function(evt) {
                this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
                this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
            }                       
        }           
    }
},
```

I tested this in IE and Chrome, I won't install Firefox anymore.

**Update to code 9/7/2017 with new stack snippet:**

```js
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C',
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function(){
                        this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stickyTracking: false,
                    events: {
                        click: function(evt) {
                          this.chart.myTooltip.options.enabled = true;
                            this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
                        },
                        mouseOut: function() {
                            this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
                            this.chart.myTooltip.options.enabled = false;
                        }                       
                    }
                    
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: @AshwinPatil, people still use browsers other than chrome :)  See updated answer...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you have tooltip `shared: true`, it's throwing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined`

Comment: @kevinandrada, this is because first parameter of myTooltip.refresh should be an array. Type this.chart.myTooltip.refresh([evt.point], evt) and the error will be gone. This will show only the clicked point though as it's going to be the only one in the array provided to the function - you need to get all the points manually.

Comment: hi @Mark. The example (jsfiddle) doesn't work anymore. Do you know how to re-solve?

Comment: @jbkunst, see new working sample code above (looks like Highcharts changed somethings internally).

Answer (score 2):

Adding for those who have problems like me with `useHTML: true` and wants to display tooltip **only** on click and not on hover.

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aespichan/0je10ur7/3/).

Comment: This solution works for me but for some reason the first time you hover over any point the tooltip is show (without clicking).

Answer (score 0):

Just add for those who has the same problems as myself (see comment from @kevinandrada just after correct answer, i can't comment): if you call `tooltip.refresh` when your `tooltip.shared = true` you'll get an exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined`.

You should provide an array of points as a first argument:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        events: {
            click: function(evt) {
                var points = this.chart.series.map(function(d) { 
                    return d.searchPoint(evt, true)
                });
                this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(points, evt);
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
                this.chart.myTooltip.hide();
            }                       
        }           
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of first mouse-over tooltip showing in Alexandra Espichán excellent fiddle can be solved via css and the mouseover event omit by replacing his invisibility class with:

```
.highcharts-tooltip:not(.clone){
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the fix for "**Cannot read category of undefined**". I just take hovered points of chart and pass them to refresh.

```
point: {
    events: {
        mouseOver: function(evt) {
            var hoveredPoints = a.hoverPoints;
            a.tooltip.refresh(hoveredPoints);   
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
            a.tooltip.hide();
        }                       
    }
}
```

Sample fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/153/