# Getting user feedback by clicking on a data point/tooltip in Highchart JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I have created a scatter plot using Highchart JS. I wish to add a check or cross button in tooltip of each data point so as to get user feedback on whether the data point displayed is in correct position. So whenever a user hovers over a data point, tooltip should be displayed with related text and a checkmark 'Yes' or cross button. I also wish to save this user feedback.

Example: Scatter plot - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

Here when I hover over a data point, I see the toooltip. I wish to add two elements to it - glyphicon glyphicon-ok and glyphicon glyphicon-remove. When user clicks on those icons, I should be able to collect that feedback suggesting whether data point shown is in correct position.

I think I should be able to do this using [click: function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click). Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please provide sample code that you're using to try to do this, so we can assist. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is problematic - when you will try to hover tooltip, with point under the tooltip, then tooltip will move to show that new point. In that case user won't be able to click on some points' 'Yes'/'No' buttons. I suggest to implement tooltip-on-click, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204419/highcharts-show-tooltip-on-points-click-instead-mouseover).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/fvufbwon/)

```
 tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        stickyTracking:falser,  
        formatter: function () {
            return "<button id=\"button\">Yes</button> &nbsp; <button id=\"button2\">No</button>";
        }
    }
```