# How to use Highcharts.Tooltip type in typescript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, typescript

I am following the example related with active the tooltip using the click event in Highchart from this url [Highcharts - Show tooltip on points click instead mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204419/highcharts-show-tooltip-on-points-click-instead-mouseover).
The thing is that I am using typescript and I can' find a correct way to translate this line to typescript:

```
 this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
```

The error what I am getting is:
"Property Tooltip doesn' exist on type HighchartsStatic"

I tried to add a new member to my controller like this:

```
   public highchartTooltip : HighchartsTooltipOptions;
```

and after :

```
this.myTooltip = new self.highchartTooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
```

But i am getting the error:
"Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature"... so i don't know  how to create a object to initialize the tooltip according the js example.

Also I can see the definition of tooltip in http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js

```
  var Tooltip = Highcharts.Tooltip = function () {
     this.init.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Tooltip.prototype = {...
```

But I can't figure out how to find it in the Typescript definition file.

The complete example in js is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/2/

I have opened a ticket in github:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9960

Any help? in some how there is a way to ignore this error? (thinking that object Highcharts.Tooltip exists when the app is runing)

Comment: HighchartsStatic? this is not in your code

Comment: I have a reference to this interface definition.. but if you see in the definition "Tooltip " doesn't exist.

Comment: You speak of a typescript definition file, which one are you using?

Comment: // Type definitions for Highcharts 2.3.3.
is that version what you are asking?

Comment: This [one](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts)?  My guess is the author of it overlooked it.

Comment: @Mark some work around to  this. thinking that I can't update to a newer version :O

Comment: It is possible to create a JSFiddle demo in Typescript (options menu in JS window has a language option). Could you create a working demo? To be honest Typescript definition file is not a official Highcharts product - its a third party solution, so you might be needing to contact its author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late answer, but perhaps this might help future users.

In the (DefinitelyTyped) [Highcharts .d.ts file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/highcharts/index.d.ts), the tooltip is not defined as a class but as an interface. Just as the [api docs mentions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip).

Which means, you're able to do the following instead with TypeScript:

```
let tooltipOptions = <Highcharts.TooltipOptions> {
    // options here...
};

let chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    tooltip: tooltipOptions
});
```