# Highcharts - show custom tooltip on mouseOver and on mouse Click

Tags: jquery, events, highcharts

I have this code:

```
events: {
                        mouseOver: function() {
                            this.chart.custom_tooltip.show();
                        },
                        click: function(evt) {
                            this.chart.custom_tooltip.bodyFormatter = function (e) {                      
                                return 'hello';
                            };
                            this.chart.custom_tooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
                        }
                    }
```

it seems it doesn't work any ideas on the approach, ive already searched about my problem but there seems to be no example where the tooltip shows on click and mouseOver, i am using a column chart btw

Comment: Could you show live example of your issue? Have you seen this SO topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204419/highcharts-show-tooltip-on-points-click-instead-mouseover

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński ive already seen that example but there is no implementation for mouseOver

Comment: I think that you can use standard tooltip for mouseover and custom tooltip for click events, look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/168/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński its working but do you know how do i custumize that tooltip to look just like m custom tooltip?

Comment: So you want to have the same tooltip for mouseOver and click? I am not sure if it is the best idea but you can see this example in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/169/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thanks for staying with me, but actaully i want the tooltip to persist if the user click on it, and can you an example using column chart? this would answer my question

Comment: So look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/170/ if it suits your needs, I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński bingo, you've got it bro, will apply this, please post your answer others might see this useful

Answer (score 1):

You can add new tooltip inside load event function of chart. Here you can see the code that may be useful in this case:

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var options = this.options.tooltip;
      this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, options);
    }
  }
},
```

Like you may read, I am making new tooltip with options of your standard tooltip.

Then on click event of your series, you may refresh your tooltip to the correct point:

```
events: {
  click: function(evt) {
    var chart = this.chart;
    chart.myTooltip.refresh(evt.point, evt);
  },
}
```

Here you can see an example how it may work: http://jsfiddle.net/2swEQ/171/